# How to store JSON array in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica, informatica-cloud

I am using IICS to do ETL. My source is a JSON file. I am using Hierarchy parser to parse that JSON and load the output into database. Everything is going fine except one thing. Within that source JSON file there is one field which is array like this:

**label:[Red, Green, Blue, Yellow].**

Now in table which I am loading data into, there is a label column of varchar2(510 byte). When data is loaded into target by running the job, label column in table gets only one value which is at last index in source array, in above case it gets only 'Yellow' value while other 3 values are lost.
*Can anybody tell me how to store entire array into the table column?*
PS: We have no flexibility to use any programming language in IICS, all that we need to do is using IICS transformations.
Please let me know if additional information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "store entire array into the table column"?  Do you want the `label` column to have, for example, a comma-separated string of values?  That would violate basic normalization of the relational model but is probably possible.  It would likely make working with the `label` column later a pain.  It sounds like `label` shouldn't be a `varchar2` column, it ought to be a child table (or at least a nested table).

Comment: Array is not  a good datatype for relational model, because if violates 1st NF. You'd better to save each element of an array as a different row in different table, which has a foreign key to the original table.

Comment: @Justin Case Yes, I want to store like that only. I want to have label column comma separated string values. But if that violates basic normalization of relational model, need to think in other way. Thanks for reply and exact answer :)

Comment: @astentx Thanks for answer. I will try to do with this way.